# ImportError when deploying Lambda function to AWS using Docker and Lambda layers

Tags: pandas, docker, aws-lambda, terraform

I am encountering an ImportError while attempting to deploy a Lambda function to AWS using Docker, Lambda layers, and Terraform CI/CD. We are using Pandas and numpy is one of its dependencies. The error message I am receiving is as follows:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'handler': Unable to import required dependencies:\nnumpy: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from\n        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch\n        your python interpreter from there.",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError",
  "requestId": "c1da53cc-ca7b-474e-838b-75280fed01a4",
  "stackTrace": []
}
```

The function logs show the following information:

```
    START RequestId: c1da53cc-ca7b-474e-838b-75280fed01a4 Version: $LATEST
[ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'handler': Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python interpreter from there.
Traceback (most recent call last):END RequestId: c1da53cc-ca7b-474e-838b-75280fed01a4
REPORT RequestId: c1da53cc-ca7b-474e-838b-75280fed01a4  Duration: 1.66 ms   Billed Duration: 2 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 48 MB  Init Duration: 294.64 ms

Request ID
c1da53cc-ca7b-474e-838b-75280fed01a4
```

We are using Docker to build the Lambda function image, Lambda layers to manage dependencies such as numpy, and Terraform CI/CD for automation of deployment.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue before when deploying Lambda functions with Docker, Lambda layers, and Terraform CI/CD? Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this ImportError would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Can you please provide the Terraform code to reproduce this issue

Comment: I don't think you can directly use Lambda layers with container based Lambda functions. Per this official blog post: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/working-with-lambda-layers-and-extensions-in-container-images/ you either need to create a containerized version of the Lambda layer, or you need to copy the layer's contents into the container. The Terraform and CI/CD stuff in your question seems irrelevant to the issue you are encountering.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to get numpy support is to add the [AWS SDK for pandas](https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) layer to your lambda:

```hcl
resource "aws_lambda_function" "lambda" {
  function_name = "test"

  filename = "lambda.zip"
  role     = aws_iam_role.iam_for_lambda.arn
  handler  = "lambda.handler"
  runtime  = "python3.9"
  layers   = ["arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:336392948345:layer:AWSSDKPandas-Python39:16"]

  source_code_hash = data.archive_file.lambda.output_base64sha256
}
```

You can get the right arn for your region here:
https://aws-sdk-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/stable/layers.html

---

I added this script to test:

```py
import logging
import numpy as np

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def handler(event, context):
    if ("ERROR" in event):
        logging.error("malfunction detected...")
    else:
        a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
        logging.info(np.add(a, a))
```

and it works fine, no import errors:
[image]

Here is the full code of my test:
https://github.com/heldersepu/hs-scripts/tree/master/TerraForm/aws_lambda_function